# Android LiveData Observer not active after first update

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying out a basic implementation of Architecture Component's Live Data with Kotlin like this:

```
class MarketFragment : LifecycleFragment(){
......
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MarketViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.book?.observe(this, Observer { book-> //updateUI })
....
```

My ViewModel class is created like this:

```
class MarketViewModel : ViewModel()
{
    var book: MutableLiveData<Book>? =MutableLiveData()
    var repository: Repository?= Repository()

    init {
        update("parameter")
    }

    fun update(s: String)
    {
         book=repository?.getBook(s)

    }

}
```

And My Repository:

```
fun getBook(bookSymbol:String):MutableLiveData<Book>
{
    val book=MutableLiveData<Book>()
    ......

            call . enqueue (object : Callback<Book> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Book>?, response: Response<Book>?) {

            book.value=response?.body()

        }
     .....
    })
            return book
}
```

}

And all of this works great and UI is updated as it should but only for the first time. If i try to make manual calls to update the viewModel from a UI action, the retrofit call still works as expected but the new data is not sent to the Observer in the Fragment:

```
//this doesn't work:
viewModel.update("string")
//This returns false:
viewModel.book.hasActiveObservers()
```

Is it the expected behaviour for an Observer to become inactive after the first trigger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are creating a new MutableLiveData instance each time you are calling `getBooks`

Hence your observer is not observing the right `LiveData` anymore.

To solve this

1. Your ViewModel should keep only one (immutable) LiveData instance
2. That immutable LiveData instance could either be:

   - A MediatorLiveData, which source is the repository's LiveData
   - A transformation of the repository's LiveData

That implies the repository method `getBooks` is only called once on initialization of the ViewModel, and that either refreshes itself OR you have to call another method on the repository to trigger a refresh.

Comment: i have a same type issue can you please look into my code...first time its triggered ....but after that onChanged isnt called until i change the configuration..

Comment: here is the link @Vincent Minmoun-Prat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341561/will-the-onchanged-method-trigger-just-as-we-change-the-data-even-if-we-dont/48342600?noredirect=1#comment83670748_48342600

Comment: Help take a look at this slightly similar question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441785/livedata-not-observing-after-first-call

Comment: Why does OP need RxJava?