# Will the `onChanged` method trigger just as we change the data? Even if we dont change the state of activity?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

Will the `onChanged` method be called if we dont change the state of the activity or restart the activity? ( **Even if the data changes** ) . If it doesnt happen how shall i make it happen ?

```
onCreate() {
    viewModel.getHolidaysDatesFromServer(..).observe(.....this,new Observer<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer>) {
        onChanged(GetHolidaysDatesFromServer GetHolidaysDatesFromServer)
    }    
}
```

and my ViewModel class ...

```
public class CalendarLifeCycleOwner extends AndroidViewModel {
    Context context;
    MutableLiveData<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> MutableLiveDataGetHolidays=new MutableLiveData<>();
    public CalendarLifeCycleOwner(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.context=application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> getHolidaysDatesFromServer(String upd_token,int product_id) {
        JustProductId justProductId=new JustProductId();
        justProductId.setProduct_id(product_id);
        UserListInterface userListInterface= UserListService.createService(UserListInterface.class, Utility.ACCEPT_HEADER_V4);
        Call<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> getHolidaysDatesFromServerCall=userListInterface.GetProductHolidays(upd_token,justProductId);
        getHolidaysDatesFromServerCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> call, Response<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    GetHolidaysDatesFromServer getHolidaysDatesFromServer=response.body();
                    MutableLiveDataGetHolidays.postValue(getHolidaysDatesFromServer);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> call, Throwable t) {
                ErrorObject errorObject=new ErrorObject(t);
                GetHolidaysDatesFromServer getHolidaysDatesFromServer=new GetHolidaysDatesFromServer();
                getHolidaysDatesFromServer.setErrorObject(errorObject);
                MutableLiveDataGetHolidays.setValue(getHolidaysDatesFromServer);

            }
        });
        return MutableLiveDataGetHolidays;
    }
}
```

But after i just change the data `onChanged()` is not getting called ...

Comment: If you restart your activity than it will be called or when you change the MutableLiveData

Comment: i have changed the data..but its not getting called unless i restart or rotate or anything ... do i always have to write `.observe(....)` to make it trigger ..?? i have observed in `oCreate` once

Comment: You need to write only once on onCreate...please post some code to be more clear

Comment: Are you using ViewModel with LiveData ??

Comment: I am using `ViewModel` with MutableLiveData ...1st time in onCreate its getting called if the data is changed ...but after that even if the data changes onChanged is not called

Comment: After i rotate or change the activity state its getting called..it isnt getting called just by changing the data ..

Comment: How you are changing the data ? please post some code

Comment: have added pseudo code...its just simple as that...i am getting the response from retrofit async using enqueue..

Comment: i am setting the value of mutablelivedata by mutablelivedata.setValue(DataObject) do i need to use .postValue instead ?

Comment: If you are changing the value from a WorkerThread or off the UIThread than you need to use postValue

Comment: same..issue both with both the operator (setValue and postValue)

Comment: Need more code to clarify the issue

Comment: Ok i am posting `ViewModel` class code

Comment: already updated code... just observed once in `onCreate`

Comment: Did you check is respone is sucessful  ? and use setValue on onResponse  method it runs on UIThread only

Comment: My code is fine i just wanna know just as the data changes does the observer gets triggered or do i need change the activity state??  and Ya i used setValue at first... both giving same result...

Comment: You don't need to change the state it will automatically updated the livedata

Comment: then it isnt but it should.. :( do i need to add anything else ?

Comment: Your code is fine..just put the debug on `onRespone()` callback and check that is it `respone.isSuccessfull()` is true ?...that's the only thing i have to say

Comment: ya thats true.. if it wasnt true ...if i rotate activity then it would throw error... just that automatically its not updating ..i am having to change the state... ok i am debugging ..

Comment: debugged...the onResponse method is called **1st time** then i change data... its not called , then i rotate ,then again its called **2nd time**

Answer (score 1):

Google actually [described](https://youtu.be/2rO4r-JOQtA?t=856) that (or very familiar to that) kind of issue as an anti-pattern on the dev-summit.
The recommended approach is to use `switchMap` from `android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations` class.
You can see the [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#switchmap) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and delete the global MutableLiveData variable

```
public MutableLiveData<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> getHolidaysDatesFromServer(String upd_token,int product_id) {

       MutableLiveData<GetHolidaysDatesFromServer> MutableLiveDataGetHolidays=new MutableLiveData<>();

       //Your API call code goes here

       return MutableLiveDataGetHolidays;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately same issue...is there any other method for retrofit callbacks?? like retrofit+viewmodel?

Comment: Just try changing the livedata value without retrofit and remove retrofit callback instead to test setValue after some duration to find the issue where it lies

Comment: then i also have to call the request after specific duration... like `for(infinite){ call.enque...}` I think this will work.. but continously i have to keep calling API

Comment: I didn't get you @SantanuSur

Comment: and it isnt working too.. :p see now i got the reason why it isnt updating but i dont know how to solve it... its not updating because **1st time as the response is received the onChanged method is called...  2nd time i update the data to server... but i am not calling the `getHolidaysDatesFromServer` 2nd time in the UI**

Comment: did u get my point ?? i have to manually call the `getHolidayDatesFromServer` after i update... but this doesnt make sense ..why shall i have to call it again after i update... (i am updating to server ) ..

Comment: Checkout my example here https://github.com/burhanrashid52/Android-Room-Data-Persistent and compare it your code