# LiveData not Observing after first Call

Tags: mvvm, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

I implemented LiveData & ViewModel to mimic AsyncTaskLoader.

I load file names from the camera directory in DCIM, and then i attach a fileObserver to Observe when a File (picture) is deleted, and then a callback tells the LiveData to re-fetch the fileNames when delete event occurs

**The Problem:**

The code below should fetch the file Names from DCIM/Pictures asynchronously with the help of LiveData and then a FileObserver is attached to the directory (DCIM/Pictures), to monitor when a file is deleted and a callback is implemented with the LiveData sub-class to reload the files, as demonstrated in code.

okay, it works the first time, that is, the files are loaded the first time, calling `setValue()` and passing the fileNames triggered onChange to be called in the observing Activity/Fragment. But when a file is deleted, the callback function calls the loadFiles() function to re-load the files again but calling the setValue and passing in the FileNames does not trigger OnChange in the observing Activity/Fragment this time around.

According to the [official documentation of LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

> You must call the setValue(T) method to update the LiveData object
>   from the main thread.

**I am curious to know why LiveData is not updating its value after the first call.**

---

**The Code**

**MyLiveData**

```
class MyLiveData() : MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>(), PictureDelete {
    override fun onPicDelete() {
        loadFileNames()
    }

    val TAG = "MyLiveData"
    val fileNamesList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    val fileWatcher : MyFileWatcher

    init {
        loadFileNames()
        val pathToWatch = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera").getAbsolutePath()
        fileWatcher = MyFileWatcher(pathToWatch, this)
        fileWatcher.startWatching()
    }

    private fun loadFileNames() {
        val fileDir: File

        try {
            fileDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.message)
            return
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Actively Loading Files in Status LiveData")

        val arrayOfFiles = fileDir.listFiles()

        if (arrayOfFiles == null || arrayOfFiles.size < 1) return

        Log.d(TAG, "Actively Loading Files. Size: ${arrayOfFiles.size}")

        setValue(fileNamesList)
    }

}
```

**MyViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val myLiveData: MyLiveData
    val TAG = "WhatsAppFragment-VModel"


    init {
        myLiveData = MyLiveData()
    }
}
```

**MyFragment**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private val TAG = "MyFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { fileNames ->
            Log.d(TAG, "New Live Data Dispatch")
            for ((index, name) in fileNames.withIndex()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "the element at $index is $name")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**MyFileObserver**

```
class MyFileWatcher(pathToWatch: String, val picDelete: PictureDelete) : FileObserver(pathToWatch, DELETE) {

    val TAG = "MyFileWatcher"

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialization")
    }

    override fun onEvent(event: Int, path: String?) {
        if (event = FileObserver.DELETE) { // EventCode 512 == Delete
            Log.d(TAG, "OnEvent. Event: $event Path: $path")
            picDelete.onPicDelete()
        }
    }
}
```

**PictureDelete Interface**

```
interface PictureDelete {
    fun onPicDelete()
}
```

What is wrong with my Implementation?

Comment: I assume because `MyFileWatcher` is bugged, but we can't see it can we?

Comment: Actually, it's working. Tested on Android 9.0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce MyFileObserver is now there.

Comment: You can use `if (event == FileObserver.DELETE)`, but apparently that seems correct. Hmm. The code seems correct, so I'd wager there is something up with the FileObserver, but I don't see why it wouldn't work atm. :|

Comment: Nothing wrong with the fileObserver, it works well. Run it on your End!

Comment: You are observing a variable. Try to observe a method that returns that variable. It is just an idea, I don't know if it will work...

Comment: and how will I do that?

Comment: so try to observe a method that returns the list of file names. When you delete a file, update the file names list, then when you update the list, the live data will be triggered. I may try to do some code later today or tomorrow, but you can try to do this.

Comment: @Micklo_Nerd i think the problem here is that you should be observing the list of file names because that is what it is going to be changed.

Comment: @joao86 could you show me in code what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have here an example @Micklo_Nerd but it does not use your problem of getting the files deleted but it gives you the idea for what you need to do.
In my example the user insert a name and after clicking a button, the list is changed.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/filename"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/filename"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filename"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/filename"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonAdd"/>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MyRepository (In your example is the MyLiveData)**

In here you must do the work of getting the filenames in the folder, and put the in the MutableLiveData.

```
class MyRepository {

    fun loadFileNames(liveData : MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>, filename: String){

       var fileList : MutableList<String>? = liveData.value

       if(test == null)
           fileList = MutableList(1){ filename }
       else
          fileList.add(filename)

       liveData.value = fileList
     }

}
```

**MyViewModel**

In here, I have two methods: one to update the list as I click the button and another to get the list of file names. You should probably only need the one that gets the list

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val repo: MyRepository
    var mutableLiveData : MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>


    init {
       repo = MyRepository()
       mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun changeList(filename: String){

       repo.loadFileNames(mutableLiveData, filename)
    }

    fun getFileList() : MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>{

      return mutableLiveData
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

In here, you see I am observing the method that returns the list of filenames, which is what you need to do, because that is what is going to change.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

   private val TAG = "MyFragment"

   private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

      viewModel.getFileList().observe(this, Observer<MutableList<String>> { fileNames ->
         Log.d(TAG, "New Live Data Dispatch")

         textView.text = ""

         for ((index, name) in fileNames!!.withIndex()) {
            textView.append("the element at $index is $name\n")
         }
      })

      buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this)
   }

   override fun onClick(v: View?) {
      when(v!!.id){
        R.id.buttonAdd -> {

            viewModel.changeList(filename.text.toString())
            filename.text.clear()
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Let me quickly run it.

Comment: @joao86 I am getting same issue can you please help me with your input how did you fix this I have posted same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897592/mutable-live-data-not-sending-value-in-fragment-second-time-in-android