# Mutable Live Data not sending value in Fragment second time in Android

Tags: android

This is my View Model :

```
class Rove2LiveVideoViewModelImpl @Inject constructor(
    override val stateLiveData: MutableLiveData<CameraR2Status>,
    private val roveR2UseCase: RoveR2UseCase,
    private val roveR2LiveVideoUseCase: RoveR2LiveVideoUseCase,
    private val appPreference: AppPreference
) : Rove2LiveVideoViewModel(), RoveR2UseCase.Callback, RoveR2LiveVideoUseCase.Callback {
    init {
        roveR2UseCase.setCallback(this)
        roveR2LiveVideoUseCase.setCallback(this)
    }
    override fun onSuccessAudioMode(response: CardStatusResponse?) {
                stateLiveData.value = AudioModeStatus(response?.status.toString())
            }
        
            override fun onSuccessUpdatedRecordingStatus(response: CardStatusResponse?) {
                stateLiveData.value = RecordingStatus(response?.status.toString())
            }
        
            override fun onSuccessSettingResponse(response: SettingsResponse?) {
                response?.let {
                    it.cmd.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                        if (item == "2007") {
                            stateLiveData.value = AudioModeStatus(it.status[index])
                        }
                    }
                    it.cmd.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                        if (item == "2001") {
                            stateLiveData.value = RecordingStatus(it.status[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

This is my fragment, I am observing it like this:

```
rove2LiveVideoViewModel.apply {
            getR2CameraConnectedOrNot()
            observe(stateLiveData, ::onRoveR2CameraResponse)
        }



private fun onRoveR2CameraResponse(state: BaseViewModel.CameraR2Status) {
        when (state) {
            is BaseViewModel.CameraR2Status.AudioModeStatus -> {
                r2VideoControlWidget.showAudioStatusIcon(state.data)
            }
            is BaseViewModel.CameraR2Status.RecordingStatus -> {
                showLiveVideoWhenR2Connected()
                when (state.data) {
                    "1" -> {
                        r2VideoControlWidget.showPlayStopButton(true)
                    }
                    "0" -> r2VideoControlWidget.showPlayStopButton(false)
                }

            }
           
        }

    }
```

first time when we call the function, I am getting call back in fragment onRoveR2CameraResponse method but when I call function again second time, I am getting call back in viewmodel from API but mutable live data not sending call back to fragment so that I can update view. Can any one help me in this? What am I doing wrong? Do we need to create different live data for each method?  Please, suggest

Comment: Try to test your code in isolation. i.e. send dummy values to 'LiveData` from `ViewModel` in some intervals, and add a console-log to observer. See if 'not receiving the update second time' is really the issue here. Injecting `LiveData` into ViewModel like this is definitely new to me.

Comment: you mean we have to send data withs some delay

Comment: I mean you should test whether your business-logic is actually setting a second value on your LiveData.

Comment: yes its in viewmodel i am getting callback but from view model to view i.e fragment i am not getting call back of mutable live  i am observing live data from fragment this is happening second time only

Comment: Have you tried not sending the MutableLiveData as an argument but instead initializing it inside the View Model?

Comment: yes i have tried every thing   in viewmodel i am getting call back but not  sending callback in viewmodel

Comment: even i tried to create new live data for each network operation then also first time its working fine but second time not getting callback

Answer (score 0):

well I've not used the Rov2 lib you are using, but it seems that the first callback you get is because of the code you use on `init` method, which will only be called once, the first time the view model is created.

Also, I notice that you are using Dependency Injection so there's a chance that the viewmodel livedata and other properties are singletons that are only created once and thus the callback is only triggered the first time.

> .. first time when we call the function ...

The code you share doesn't show what function you are calling or when. The liveData object is only updated through a callback which code doesn't show how it is called.